# How do I export a notebook from RCloud (into Text/Word etc)

Tags: python, r, rcloud

Does anyone know how to export RCloud notebooks (not RStudio) to a **common** format?  I’m using it for a project to try to predict if a car will statistically be a good purchase or a lemon, and I’m learning - so I’m trying a lot of new/different code and packages to make graphs, regression charts etc.

I’m new to RCloud so I want to save this notebook as a reference document/cheat sheet on my laptop so I can ‘reuse’ the common R commands I used (e.g. how to use "*lapply*" command to change vectors to numeric like *“mycarsub[, 1:6] <- lapply(mycarsub[, 1:6], as.numeric”, "na.omit"*, etc.  I just want a reference to use for other projects or notebooks in Rcloud, RStudio etc.

So I’m wondering if anyone knows how to export it in Text format that is searchable or easily read with common apps (outside of RCloud, or RStudio)?  Like export to Word/Libreoffice, HTML etc?

I tried “Share” at the top but think it only exports R file types, I’m probably doing it wrong.  Or if you have another way to accomplish what i'm trying to do.  I cut and pasted but doesn't work all the time (user error?).  I searched Stack Overflow but only got RStudio or R developer code exporting via API's etc.  Hope this is enough info, first post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[RCloud](https://rcloud.social/index.html) was created for making it easier to share code and for others to learn from existing code so it includes the ability to search code using Lucene search syntax. Rather that creating another document to keep track of, I would suggest opening multiple RCloud tabs - use one to search, cut and paste from and the other to code in; you can create multiple tabs by copying and pasting any notebook URL into a new tab.

[image: RCloud Public Instance]

If you prefer to have a separate document, you can export the RCloud notebooks as an R Source file or a Rmarkdown file using the Advanced menu located in the navigation bar at the far right.

[image: RCloud Advanced Menu Options]